# Microsoft BI Report with Input

Tags: report, user-input, business-intelligence

I need to create a Microsoft BI Produced Report, that will display **Actual Data**, retrieved from database. But I also want users to be able to fill **Forecast Data** for next month in the column beside the reported actual data, and the inputted data will be loaded to Forecast Cube.

Is it possible to do it ? What is the right strategy ?

Thanks for your input :) !

Answer (score 0):

MS BI products are based on reporting, so they don't have any direct ways to interact with the data like you're asking. There are several options that start with an SSRS report though (or a PowerPivot book etc.).

SharePoint Workflow - allows a lot of other control aspects to the input process. Pickup the list with an ETL package.
You could also do a similar thing with a simple web app. Link either through a report action.

ETL - Make the report exportable to excel and leave blank columns for user input. Re-absorb it through an ETL process that reads the modified Excel file. This can be a manually triggered job, not necessarily part of a DM/DW nightly ETL.

You could also just have a manual script. I would think and hope that the forecast data isn't changed that often, so a simpler solution would probably be best.